# android low battery indication

Tags: android, battery

How should the linux driver indicate low battery indication to the user space ?
I do not find any support for this in power_supply.h. Is the android service supposed to handle this by reading the battery capacity ?

Highyl appreciate efforts to answer this query.

Thanks
Ganesh.

Comment: I would more like to know how the flow of the battery Low indication percolates from the linux kernel space to the linux user space

Answer (score 0):

add this code

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {          
          int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
          // level...... it will show the battery information
          // you can use this variable to show the battery information.               
      }
};
```

and

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Comment: What is tv_battery? And where do I add the intentFilter line?

Comment: Here tv_battery means text view to show the battery information.